# Excel to Dataframe to SQL in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I have an excel file with 2 sheets that I wish to manipulate using SQL in a Jupyter Notebook. I remember a long time ago going through some tutorial that explained you can use SQL within Python just by adding %sql before each line. But from google searches I can't figure out how to get this to work. It seems I need to create a database and then a connection, etc. But the database is just going to be the pandas dataframes I've already imported, I don't need to connect to any external database, right? (Sorry I know it must sound like such a stupid question but I've never created my own databases before).

Here's what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite://

path = (my file path)
orders = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name = 1)
items = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name = 2)

%sql select * from orders
```

Then I get an error:

```
* sqlite://
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: orders
[SQL: select * from orders]
```

Comment: Why do you want to use SQL instead of pandas? `select * from orders` is the same as just calling the variable `orders`

Comment: Because I want to join the tables and manipulate them with groupby, etc. Yes I could do it  with pandas but it's easier with SQL.

Comment: `orders.merge(items, on='some_key', how='inner').groupby('key')` Check out [Pandas Comparison with SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html)

Comment: @Seb  While I'm not able to answer your question specifically, I generally agree w/probably everyone else that it's actually much easier to do in pandas, if you're willing to learn.  Unless there's a supreme time crunch to deliver the answer, I would suggest giving pandas a shot.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I'll just use pandas then, thanks.